# refinerycms 2.0.3, specify stylesheets for page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I would like to specify a css which applies only when I'm on a page. I didn't find the solution.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In config file pages.rb
Make flag true for
config.use_view_templates = true

It will provide you the option for select template for that page .
You can find it under admin pages tab -> Advanced Options.

Also you need to add template name in pages.rb
config.view_template_whitelist

Now you can add your styles on that page.
Hope it helps you.